# Where is the section of the law for USA that talks about ROMs?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

Where can I find what the law says about obtaining video game ROMs (as in downloading them from online sources)? When I tried googling all I found were people telling what the law says but the answers varied. I want to know straight from the source what the law says about obtaining ROMs if you already own the game.

EDIT: I'm in USA.

Comment: What jurisdiction?  Which countries laws are you interested in?

Comment: What's "obtaining"? The applicable law will depend on how exactly you obtain.

Comment: It isn't likely that any legislature has considered ROMs specificially and decided to make a law about them; instead, they make more general laws about copyright, and courts have to decide how to interpret those laws to apply to situations like what you describe.  So I don't think you'll find a "clear-cut, straight-from-the-source" answer like you're looking for.

Comment: @Moo sorry it is USA

Comment: @Greendrake obtaining would be downloading ROMs from online sources

Answer (score -1):

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

[Copyright Act 1968](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Series/C1968A00063) *Cth*

Comment: Hi I apologize didnt realize I needed to add my jurisdiction. Do you have the laws for USA?